# Software Development Environment Locking up entirely

Tags: windows-7, windows, anti-virus, development

Currently, our software developers are working with MSVC and have certain parts of their build process reach out to files on the network. Theres one portion of the build process in which they use a utility to translate all of the language resource files into other languages in an automated fashion via a dictionary tool. The boxes these devs are working on are windows 7 32bit boxes. The 64 bit boxes do not have this compilation issue. We've recently determined that with the antivirus software (Trend Micro) unloaded, the build process does not lock up (it primarily locked up during the translations). With the antivirus software loaded, the build process would lockup with 100% CPU utilization. Roughly a month ago, out of the blue, the build process ran completely fine. Within the past week, the issue has risen once again. Any ideas one what could be the cause of this?

Comment: You answered it yourself: it's the antivirus. Maybe you can exclude the files or directories from being scanned.

Comment: Problem is we've contacted the AV vendor, who did not provide any assistance. We've also tried exclusion and whitelisting, which did not work. Im curious on whether or not the AV scans objects in memory even if they come from whitelisted/excluded sources.